# How do I get my AMQP 1.0 consumer to keep track of messages already consumed using ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic, amqp, qpid

I am using a ActiveMQ AMQP broker, every time I run my consumer I get all the message in the queue.  This is good, however I need a way to limit the messages I read based on what I have not already read the prior time I ran my consumer.  What I mean is, I only want to see new messages.  Is there a way to send an offset to ActiveMQ broker or to send it some sort of unique identifier so that it knows what I already consumed and it only sends me newer content?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are not really supposed to keep data around in the broker when it's been read. ActiveMQ is a temporary storage, not a database. Keeping old data around on purpose will have multiple implications - specifically in the persistence store if using persistent messages.

I guess you are not acking/commiting the transaction or browsing the queue. If you commit the transaction after you have read your message/messages then they will be removed and will not appear the next time you attempt to read the queue.

Comment: Peter can you give me an example on how to ack/commit the transaction, I am using 
t = mng.get(msg)
mng.accept(t)
But I can not get it to work.